# How to set EventListener for table of buttons with no unique id for each one?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I’m trying to make a battleship game, the table is made up by 10 rows and 10 columns of buttons with no unique id for each

```
<table id="myTable">
      <tr >
        <td><button type="button"></button></td>
        <td><button type="button"></button></td>
        <td><button type="button"></button></td>
        <td><button type="button"></button></td>
        <td><button type="button"></button></td>
        <td><button type="button"></button></td>
        <td><button type="button"></button></td>
        <td><button type="button"></button></td>
        <td><button type="button"></button></td>
        <td><button type="button"></button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr >
        <td><button type="button"></button></td>
        <td><button type="button"></button></td>
        <td><button type="button"></button></td>
        <td><button type="button"></button></td>
        <td><button type="button"></button></td>
        <td><button type="button"></button></td>
        <td><button type="button"></button></td>
        <td><button type="button"></button></td>
        <td><button type="button"></button></td>
        <td><button type="button"></button></td>
      </tr>
    <!-- it's quite longer-->
</table>
```

to get the coordinates of the cell when any button is clicked, I did this
but I returns

```
table.addEventListener("click",function(){
    let col=this.closest('td').index();
    let row=col.closest('tr').index();
    shot([row,col]);
});
```

but the console throws typeError for this keyword

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘index’ of null

Comment: Are you using jQuery? I ask because `.index()` is a jQuery function.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using jquery. (there isn't index method in js)
try to use target event

```js
table.addEventListener("click",function(event){
    let col= $(event.target).closest('td').index();
    let row= $(event.target).closest('tr').index();
    shot([row,col]);
});
```

also needs to check if target event is td or tr which you need

Comment: could you do it using DOM?

Comment: event.target.closest('td') works in DOM. but there isn't index method in DOM. Can you dynamically (with js) add id (which will be index) to every elements and then use it?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I believe you're misunderstanding the `closest` method. `closest` returns the closest **ancestor**, not child, and it is relative to the html hierarchy rather than mouse position ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)).

Secondly, easiest would be to add event listeners to the individual cells:

```
[...table.querySelectorAll('tr')].forEach((row, rowI) =>
    [...row.querySelectorAll('td')].forEach((cell, colI) =>
        cell.addEventListener("click", () => shot([rowI, colI]))));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the buttons using the the table `id` and `querySelectorAll`. The ise closest to get the tr & td and then use `cellIndex` and `rowIndex`

```js
document.getElementById('myTable').querySelectorAll('button').forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let td = item.closest('td').cellIndex ;
    let tr = item.closest('tr').rowIndex;
    console.log(tr, td)
  })
})
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td><button type="button"></button></td>
    <td><button type="button"></button></td>
    <td><button type="button"></button></td>
    <td><button type="button"></button></td>
    <td><button type="button"></button></td>
    <td><button type="button"></button></td>
    <td><button type="button"></button></td>
    <td><button type="button"></button></td>
    <td><button type="button"></button></td>
    <td><button type="button"></button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button type="button"></button></td>
    <td><button type="button"></button></td>
    <td><button type="button"></button></td>
    <td><button type="button"></button></td>
    <td><button type="button"></button></td>
    <td><button type="button"></button></td>
    <td><button type="button"></button></td>
    <td><button type="button"></button></td>
    <td><button type="button"></button></td>
    <td><button type="button"></button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

if use DOM API only, you have to calculate the index yourself.

```
    document.querySelector('#myTable').addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        let tr = e.target.closest('tr');
        let td = e.target.closest('td');
        let col = Array.from(tr.children).indexOf(td);
        let row = Array.from(this.rows).indexOf(tr);
        alert([row, col]);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

recently I found out this

```
table.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  let ele=e.target.closest('td');
  let cIndex=ele.cellIndex;
  let rIndex=ele.parentElement.rowIndex;
  shot([rIndex,cIndex]);
});
```